# add/remove Class transition does not work

Tags: jquery

I have a menu made by a "ul" list. I have 2 classes for hover style and normal. I want to animate the transition between those 2 classes at mouseover.

I have this html:

```
<ul class="mainNav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Classes:

> forHover, notHover

jQuery 1.9.1 ; UI 1.10.1

jQuery code:

```
$('.mainNav li:not(:last-child)').hover(function(){

    $(this).addClass("forHover",3000);
    return false;
},function(){

    $(this).removeClass("forHover",3000);
    return false;

});
```

The hover effect works ok but there is no transition. Why not?

Comment: What do you get from `console.log($.ui)` Note: in your current code, you aren't using `notHover`

Comment: You could use CSS3 transitions for the hover states

Comment: @Horen You can with jQuery UI: http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/

Comment: Object {version: "1.10.1", keyCode: Object, ie: false, plugin: Object, hasScroll: function…}

Comment: @KevinB that's pretty awesome - didn't know that.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to animate? width? height? color?

Comment: The transition between 2 classes like switchclass function.

Comment: @Krayz right, but what exactly are the styles you are animating? Show your css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the [**addClass**](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [**removeClass**](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) from the standard jQuery API.

You need to reference the jQuery UI API for the UI version.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zc8Py/) -- Using the UI API reference jQuery UI 1.10.1 works fine

---

I downloaded the effects of the 1.10.1 version and added it to the DEMO above.
The DEMO is using your exact same versions and all is working. There is some other localized issue you are experiencing as jQuery UI works out-of-the-box.

Maybe some other API or plug-in you are referencing is overwriting `$.ui` or similar

Demo is using your code as is and jQuery 1.9.1 + jQuery UI 1.10.1 as you are:

```
$('.mainNav li:not(:last-child)').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("forHover", 3000);
    return false;
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("forHover", 3000);
    return false;
});
```

**Edit**

I checked out your site you are linking and even after using your exact `forHover` CSS it still works in latest Chrome, Firefox and IE10.

I wasn't able to fully see and understand what all the other JavaScript in your file was trying to do but I would have to guess that somewhere in there you are doing something to those menu items which somehow counteracts the animation effect.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zc8Py/1/) - using the CSS from your actual forHover

---

**Edit**

I see now what is happening. Using the developer tools you can see when selecting the `li` that when hovering over the menu items the `forHover` is applied but is immidiatly overwritten by your `.mainNav li, .notHover {` style! Hence all the styles in the `forHover` are struck-through.

Your CSS is clashing!

A dirty quick-fix is adding `!important` to the `forHover` styles, that should make them work but it is a dirty fix.

It would be better to assign the CSS from `.mainNav li, .notHover {` to just `.notHover` , assigning `notHover` to the `li` elements by default and then use jQuery UI's `switchClass`, similar to this (code below is untested but syntax should be right):

```
$('.mainNav li:not(:last-child)').hover(function () {
    $(this).switchClass("notHover", "forHover", 3000);
    return false;
}, function () {
    $(this).switchClass("forHover", "notHover", 3000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: He is referencing it, see comments.

Comment: @kraYz: See updated answer. I updated DEMO to use jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.1 matching the versions you specified in your question and it seems to work fine. Seeing you can't even get it working with jQuery UI 1.9.2 you have a more localized issue. Maybe something else is possibly overwriting your jQuery UI reference. All versions work fine in a jsFiddle.

Comment: @kraYz: Something else is interfering with your animation. Even when I use your `forHover` style with the webkit CSS it still works in latest Chrome, IE10 and latest FireFox. IE9 is going crazy on the animation but still kind-of animates in some way. http://jsfiddle.net/zc8Py/1/

Comment: @KevinB: Yes, you are correct. I seen it in the link to the actual page linked by `kraYz` above. I checked the jQuery UI file and `addClass:` function is defined and included. It should animate the background color. I tried looking at the `.js` file from the site but I wasn't able to see which part of the script is interfering with the animation.

Comment: @kraYz: See my latest edit, your CSS is clashing. `.mainNav li, .notHover {` CSS in style.css line 43 is overwriting the effects of `forHover` in style.css line 51. Bascially when hovering over the menu items `forHover` is added but over-written by the styles applied to `.mainNav li`. Quick-fix: add `!important` to the `forHover` CSS and it should work but that's a dirty fix.

Comment: I found the solution $('.mainNav li a').hover(function() instead of $('.mainNav li').hover(function(). Hover of jQuery seems to work only on links in my case. I'll accept your answer anyway.Thank you!

Comment: @kraYz: Ah, I see. I assumed you wanted the `li` elements to be the targets and tried fixing that. Glad you got it worked out though in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate background images with jQuery UI's effects methods.

http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/

> Not all styles can be animated. For example, there is no way to animate a background image. Any styles that cannot be animated will be changed at the end of the animation.